# Braintree: creating subscription in the middle of the billing cycle

Tags: payment-gateway, braintree, payment-processing

In braintree's sandbox I have created a plan with a monthly cycle with billing on the 1st of every month. Now, when a customer signs up in the middle of the month I would like to charge the prorated amount for the current month but I do not want to set the billing date to the current day of the month.

Are there any options in the Subscription API that I could use? (the only thing I see is overriding the billing date of the plan).

I could create a separate transaction for the current month, but it would be more convenient to have an active subscription from the moment the user signs up. Our product is priced on a per user basis. We thought we could have an add-on for every user - every time the customer adds a new user we would add an add-on to the subscription and let braintree prorate the charges. But that will only work with an active subscription. Without a subscription we would need to calculate the amount ourselves and create a separate transaction.

I'm new to braintree / payment gateways; maybe there are other ways of approaching this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).

Your method of creating a separate transaction for the current month, and creating a subscription for the user for the next month is a proper way of handling it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want subscription to be created then create two subcriptions at same time.
Set one as immediate payment and give the discount on pro rata basis the days have passed and restrict it to 1 billing cycle only. The second one should be normal.